# Image Editor does not show RGBA output from composite viewer

Tags: node-editor, image, compositing-nodes

blender 2.91, I have a problem with Composite viewer node - I'm trying to preview contents using Image Editor however despite having all checkbox set Image Editor does not shows full output, particularly excludes alpha channel.

Any idea what's happening?

As you can see in the picture below I have "Use Alpha" set everywhere, Image Editor is in RGBA mode, yet there's alpha output lacking in the image editor. I tried to disconnect/connect nodes in the compositor, to force refresh, but no result

[image]

Comment: Is it intended that the Red channel goes into the Alpha input of the _Combine RGBA_ node? Otherwise, an image of the Alpha channel would be interesting, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alpha channel has not been associated with the image.

To associate the alpha channel use an **Alpha Convert** node and set it to Straight to Premultiplied.

[image]